# Correctly setting imports in a file meant to be imported

Tags: python, python-module

I'm building a small Python package. Following https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/, I have a file structure like so:

```
pkg/
    - src/
        - pkg/
            - __init__.py
            - file.py
```

whith ClassA, ClassB, etc. defined in file.py

I've installed this package on my system. I can now do things like `import pkg.file`
in an interpreter, which is great. However, it gives me access to whatever not starting with _ in file.py; including all the imports, global variables, etc. that live in this file. I'm happy with pkg.file.ClassA; less so with, for instance, pkg.file.itertools, or pkg.file.PI. It just doesn't feel very clean.

What would be the best practice here? Modifying my import statements in file.py as `import itertools as _itertools`? Some pythonic trickery in the init file? I thought of adding `from file import ClassA, ClassB` to it, but it doesn't seem very DRY to me. Additionally, file.py is susceptible to being broken into two or more files in the near future.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to structure a Python module to limit exported symbols?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26813545/how-to-structure-a-python-module-to-limit-exported-symbols)

Comment: @CryptoFool Not quite; it gives some useful pointers though. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I came up with a two-stage process:

- setting `__all__ = ['ClassA', 'ClassB']` at the top level in file.py;
- adding `from .file import *` in init.py.

This way, on `ìmport pkg` I have directly access to my classes in the namespace pkg. As a side effect, I'm quite happy with this flattening of the hierarchy!
pkg.file.whatever are still accessible, a way to circumvent that would be great (for cleanness if anything else) but I can live with it.